# Dificuldades em converter sintaxes de Classe para Função no React Native

Tags: react, react-native

Comecei meus estudos de React Native através de um curso que comprei, porém o professor só ensina a usar como classe, e eu queria ficar por dentro de como faz em função (Que pelo que eu vi é a maneira mais "moderna")
Então, como ficaria esse código em contexto de função com o **export default function App( ) { }**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { View, Text} from 'react-native';
    
    
    export default class App extends Component {
    
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          nome: 'Filipe'
        };
      }
    
      render() {
        return(
          <View>
            <Text> {this.state.nome} </Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue exemplo:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [nome, setNome] = useState("Filipe");

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{nome}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Recomendo a leitura destes artigos se quiser aprender mais sobre componentes funcionais para React / React Native e sobre a API de Hooks.

https://www.reactnative.express/react/components/function_components
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: Obrigadão. vou dar uma lida nos artigos